Polimorphism when only 1 subclass change the method
I have a base class (IDistribution) with a simple virtual method Generate().
Now i want to define all types of distributions so i create a class for every distribution and inside of that class i have different type of data like:
in UniformDistribution i have uniform_distribution and its parameters from the random.h lib, in ExponentiolDistribution i have exponentiol_distribution and so on...
The problem is that the virtual method body is the same foreach sub class like : distribution(generate);
except form the RandomDisttribution where Generate() has different implementation.
class IDistribution {
public:
  default_random_device rng;
  virtual void generate() = 0;
}
class UniformDistribution : IDistribution {
private:
 uniform_distribution dist;
public:
  virtual void generate() {
    dist(rng());
  };
}
class ExponentialDistribution : IDistribution {
private:
 exponential_distribution dist;
public:
  virtual void generate() {
    dist(rng());
  };
}
class RandomDistribution : IDistribution {
public:
  virtual void generate() {
    /*Other implementaion*/
  };
}

Is polimorphism still a good idea to to this or i need so switch to enums?
Edit: (i decide what type of distribution i want at runtime)

Post code instead of description of code.

Also refer to [mcve]

template might be an option.

You could consider static polymorphism instead of dynamic polymorphism.

Instead of using polymorphism (class inheritence) use a template,   e.g.  Distribution<Generator>, where Generator is an object with a specified interface (set of accessible member functions with required signatures).   As long as your Distribution class only uses the generator's interface, it doesn't need to care how each generator is implemented.

Unless you want to be able to switch strategies at runtime. you can use template (static polymorphism) just as @Peter describes. If you want to switch at runtime an interface (abstract baseclass) is totally fine. It is even nice for unit testing (dependency injection) although that would work with templates too

So TLDR, what is your use case do you want to switch algorithms (strategies) at runtime or not?

@Peter good idea, but i wouldn`t be code repetition still? all the generators have the same code except the Random one

@Pepijn Kramer yes at runtime, i even saw the strategy pattern but my fear is code repetition, like every method body is the same, the only thing that changes is the type of dist object

Then inheritance is just fine, as long as you actually return a value instead of void ;)

@Pepijn Kramer ye, i put void for the example xd

@genoveffoeskere   The requirement is that the generators present the same interface.   If you have a number of generators with common implementation, you can (optionally) use a class hierarchy (virtual functions that get overridden/specialised, etc) as needed to help with code reuse.   If you want, you can have a bunch of generators that all inherit from a common base class, and other generators that don't.

@Peter so you meant to create a distribution template foreach type of distribution and then passing a type of generator?

You should always ask yourself what you're doing when an interface has a member variable. That's an implementation detail.

@genoveffoeskere like every method body is the same, the only thing that changes is the type of dist object -- Isn't that the problem that templates solvem i.e. you have the same code, only the type is different?  For example std::vector<int> and std::vector<Widget> have different types, but the same code.  There is no code duplication there.

@PaulMcKenzie i forgot to mention that i want this thing to be at runtime but i don`t understand how to do it without code duplication

So have your template class manage a pointer to the generator.   Then make your generators polymorphic (derived from a common base class) and control the generation at run time by selecting what type of generator is created - but the templated class still interacts with the generator via the same interface.    Incidentally,  you're mistaken if you expect to eliminate code duplication entirely - available techniques can - with care- be used to reduce or even minimise the amount of code duplication, but that rarely means NO duplication.

@Peter im so sorry but i dont understand what the differences are then? if the generators are polymorphic isn`t the same as my code?

Your approach is making the Distribution class polymorphic, and each derived class has members and (if the generators have a common interface) replicated code to manage a different type of contained generator.   The option I'm suggesting is for the Distribution class to be non-polymorphic, but manage a generator via a (possibly smart) pointer and a consistent interface
